# Organize Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I retrieve data from a function and store it in a Javascript array that is structured in the following way.

When i print my array, i get the follwoing

```
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-07,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
2014-03-22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-09,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-12,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
2014-03-25,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-26,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-08,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
2014-03-16,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-13,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
2014-03-10,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,
2014-03-14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-31,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
2014-04-02,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-30,4,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,
2014-03-21,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-06,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-05,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-27,6,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,
2014-03-15,2,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,
2014-03-17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-24,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-28,17,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,
2014-04-01,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-29,3,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
2014-03-18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
2014-03-20,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
```

I would like to modify the above array so that it appears in the following way and then store the contents in a csv file

```
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-07,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-09,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-12,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-25,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
day,views,likes,shares,comments,dislikes,estimatedMinutesWatched,favoritesAdded,favoritesRemoved,
2014-03-26,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are 'day', 'views' etc labels for the data?

Comment: For a csv, you'll need some structure for the data. Labels usually go on the first line and a record follows each newline thereafter. Since you have everything in one array, you'll have to make assumptions about the number of fields in a record. Unless you can actually get the data in a more structured form.

Comment: Yes, day', 'views' are label views for the data

Answer (score 0):

If i have well anderstood, You have a one dimension array and you want a matrix?

Here you have 9 labels right? so the you can use :

```
function arrayToMatrix(array, colums) {
    var matrix = [], size = array.length;    
    for (i = 0, k = -1; i < size; i++) {
        if (i % colums=== 0) {
            k++;
            matrix[k] = [];
        }    
        matrix[k].push(array[i]);
    }    
    return matrix;
}
```

So use :

```
var matrix = arrayToMatrix(array,9);
```

Then you have to print that in CSV.

```
function matrixToCSV(matrix){
     var result = '';
     for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
          for (var j = 0; i < matrix[i].length; j++){ //print each line
              if (j == 0 ){
                   result += matrix[i][j];
              }else{
                   result += ',' + matrix[i][j];
              }              
          }
          result += ';\n'; //new line
     }
     return result;
}
```

And then :

```
var CSVFile = matrixToCSV(matrix);
```

NOTE: In CSV, you don't need to repeat the labels.

Comment: Thanks very much. can you please give me the Csv function too ?

Comment: @user3172841 is it ok for you?

Comment: i am getting a ReferenceError: list is not defined on this line  

matrix[k].push(list[i]);

Comment: @user3172841 I have edited my code since the first time : it's not 'list' but 'array'